# Rails 4 Postgresql array data-type: updating values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am just starting to use the array data-type in Postgres with Rails 4 but I am having trouble getting values on an existing array to update.  I have a column called 'quantity' that is an array of integers( [0,0] ).  I want to update the value at 'quantity[0]' and I have tried the following in the console:

```
a = Asset.find(2) 
=> #<Asset id: 2, quantity: [0,0]>

a.quantity[0] = 5
=> 5 

a.quantity_will_change! 
=> [5, 0] 

a.save
=> true

a.reload
=> #<Asset id: 2, quantity: [0,0]>
```

As you can see, the asset object's quantity value is change but when I try to save the object using 'a.save' the change is not reflected when I reload the object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `quantity_will_change!` or replacing the whole array should work. Is there something going on that we can't see?

Comment: @muistooshort : you were 100% correct.  I had a callback on my model that was altering the values.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reading of http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty is that you have to call `..._will_change!` *before* you change the attribute. You should be able to confirm this by examining `changes` under various scenarios.

Update: I just tested the behavior with a string attribute, and it still saves the updated string even if the change was made before `..._will_change` is called, so my interpretation may be off.

Comment: Hey Peter, I have tried using _quantity_will_change!_ both before and after setting the value.  The _changes_ method does in fact show that the value was changed.  Any other ideas?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is what @muistooshort indicated, that something else is going on (e.g. within your model that is "resetting" things).

Answer (score 1):

`<attribute>_will_change!` will only update value if array has been replaced. In-place modifications like `[]=` won't be saved at all.